# How can I create div elements which are like a table with border

Tags: html, css, box

I was wondering.. how can I make my div elements like boxes but without using the element "table" for border draw. So far I was using the table element, but when I was having longer sentences, the box itself widened, which messed up with my design:

http://postimg.org/image/qjp8u01ox/

Usually, the center column widens as well, when texts overgo the width of the column.
I've tried the overflow attribute to be hidden, but then again, the text the rest of the text is cut, instead of going for a new line.

I would like it to be like the e107 CMS side menus. Example:

http://clanwebs.co.uk/images/codww.jpg

But I guess they are using some images, and write text through this image.

Edit: My code: jsfiddle.net/Xz8x4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the all the content into a div with a specified width. I write a little example to show you how it works.

css:

```
.body{
    text-align:center;
    width:80%;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.right{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.center{
    float:left;
    width:60%
}
```

html:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="left">
    test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div>
</div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mihutz/ba2eA/1/

You need a max-width:

```
#leftmenu td, #centercol td, #rightmenu td {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:1px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mihutz/Xz8x4/2/

Comment: I've done it in a similar fashion, but still not working, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz8x4/

Comment: the box is fixed, thanks a lot, but only the text problem is left, it still continues outside the container, how can I make it go for a new line it it exceeds its limit?(I've removed the overflow attribute because it cuts the text otherwise.. )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not setting the `width` property at all.

Set `width: 100px` and it would stay in its limits. Otherwise it is `auto` and the browser would try to elongate it untill all of the text is wrapped or the far right side is met.

Comment: I've tried this a couple of times, still no result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rightmost column text is longer than the space it has, so you can set `word-break: break-all;` to break that text into multiple lines, although it has no spaces.

If the real text that goes in that column fits well in it or has spaces so that it can be broken up into multiple lines, then there would be no problem.

This 3-column layout is called the Holy Grail layout. Maybe this can be of help to you:

- [Liquid (and fixed-width) Holy Grail layout code example (HTML & CSS).](http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/index.htm)
- [Liquid Holy Grail layout using Flexbox.](http://appendto.com/2014/03/solving-the-holy-grail-layout/)